# Confused about passing up flag to parent from child Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm going through tutorials and documentation and it keeps referencing clicks events with outputs and event emitters to pass data from child to parent. This seems overcomplicated for what I'm doing. I have a parent file that needs to access a boolean from a child component.

Parent

```
<start-application-button-link 
     [buttonText]="buttonText"
     isDisabled="buttonDisabled">
</start-application-button-link>
```

Child

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myFlag = true;
};
```

I want access of this.myFlag in the parent file

Comment: https://www.newline.co/@ptlergo/replace-@output-@input-and-eventemitters-with-viewchild-for-component-interaction--49bef22d

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a template reference variable, the `#child`

```
<start-application-button-link #child
     [buttonText]="buttonText"
     isDisabled="buttonDisabled">
</start-application-button-link>
```

Now you have access to all the functions and public variables of the parent.

Form the .html you can, e.g.

```
<button (click)="giveMeValue(child.myFlag)">
<start-application-button-link #child ...>
```

Form the .ts you need use ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('child') myChild:StartApplicationButtonComponent;
//or -in this case you needn't use the template reference variable
@ViewChild(StartApplicationButtonComponent) myChild:StartApplicationButtonComponent;

//and in any place
console.log(this.myChild.myFlag)
```