# How to call onInit from different component when button is pressed?

Tags: angular, typescript, function, components

I'm trying to make it so my screen updates the reservations after I made a reservation (which you create when pressing the button), but I can't seem to make it update after I pressed the button

new-reservation-component.html

```
<button (click)="onButtonClick()" mat-raised-button class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button>
```

new-reservation-component.ts

```
private scheduleComponent: ScheduleComponent
 onButtonClick() {
    this.scheduleComponent.ngOnInit()
     //also tried calling the other functions by making them public like fetchReservation 
  }
```

schedule component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {Reservation} from "../../reservation.model";
import {ReservationsHttpService} from "../../reservations-http.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.scss']
})
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  isFetching = false;
  error: any = null
  private errorSub: Subscription;

  reservations: Reservation[] = [];

  weekYear_ReservationMap: Map<string, Reservation[]> = new Map<string, Reservation[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private reservationHttpService: ReservationsHttpService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.errorSub = this.reservationHttpService.error.subscribe(errorMessage => {
      this.error = errorMessage;
    });
    this.fetchReservations();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.errorSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  private mapReservationsToWeekYear(): Map<string, Reservation[]> {
    let reservationMap = new Map<string, Reservation[]>();
    for (let reservation of this.reservations.sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1)) {

      let isWeekOfNextYear = ( reservation.date.getMonth() + 1 == 12
        && reservation.getWeekNumber() == 1); // To group according to ISO 8601.
      // curMonthYearKey is also the header displayed in the template.
      let curMonthYearKey = (reservation.date.getFullYear() + (isWeekOfNextYear ? 1 : 0)) + " - Week: " + reservation.getWeekNumber();
      let curMonthYearArray = reservationMap.get(curMonthYearKey) || [];

      curMonthYearArray.push(reservation);
      reservationMap.set(curMonthYearKey, curMonthYearArray || []);
    }
    return reservationMap;
  }

  private fetchReservations(){
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.reservationHttpService.fetchOpenReservations()
      .subscribe((reservations) => {
        this.reservations = reservations;
        this.weekYear_ReservationMap = this.mapReservationsToWeekYear();
        this.isFetching = false;
      }, (error) => {
        this.error = error;
        this.isFetching = false;
      }
    )

  }
}
```

I tried making an attribute to use the functions of schedule component.ts, but it doesn't work, I also tried to change OnInit to DoCheck, OnChanges, OnViewChanges etc, but that doesn't work as well (or does work but sends so many requests that my site crashes, like when I try DoCheck or AfterContentChecked)

I also tried doing
@ViewChild(ScheduleComponent) scheduleComponent:ScheduleComponent;
and then doing
this.scheduleComponent.ngOnInit()
but that also doesn't work

And I tried using the functions from schedule.ts, ngOnDestroy, fetchReservation and OnInit, but with no luck

Comment: It seems weird to manually call `ngOnInit`, but the reason it isn't firing is because you left out the `()`: `(click)="onButtonClick()"`

Comment: I changed that, thanks
But now I get a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ngOnInit')" error message

Comment: To "reach" the scheduleComponent you need use "ViewChild" or use a template reference variable if they have relation child-parent like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075243/confused-about-passing-up-flag-to-parent-from-child-angular-typescript/75076054#75076054) or, if not  use a service like indicate in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service). I know that the tittle looks like it's only to components that have child-parent relation, but **it's the way** to comunicate two components not parent-cjhild too

Comment: You should pass the data to the component through an input. The component can react to data changes through ngOnChanges or the input itself. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `fetchReservations` when the button is clicked?